# RESTful API Auth flow

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel

I've been on stack overflow for the last hour researching this topic so I thought I'd just ask all my specific questions. I'm building a web app currently using Laravel (PHP) for the API and Angular for the front. I've looked at oAuth but it's a little daunting atm so I was hoping to implement a simpler solution and then rebuild it in when necessary.

The flow I'm currently implements goes as follows. Angular posts the user credentials (over https) to my rest backend and this simply returns a generated string (this will probably be random or crytographicaly generated). This string is then stored as a cookie or whatever browser state I find suitable and then attached to every API request along with a user id that angular makes as an extra parameter or request header or something. The API uses this to check if the user has access to the requested resource and responds accordingly. I'd probably also add a expiry time on the string which would be reset after every request.

My question is really if this is an acceptable flow? In terms of security what issues am I most likely to face with this? CSRF? Session fixation?

I know this is a question that's been asked a couple times before but I was just hoping for a fresh discussion and be pointed towards relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you input everyone. Ultimately I decided to have a look into OAuth 2 again as suggested. What I was trying to create was pretty much an OAuth flow anyway... Instead of trying to recreate the wheel I looked at other people's implementations of OAuth in PHP (and Laravel) and this practical implementation really helped me get the idea.

I used this package in the end

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server

Wrapped for laravel

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

I was a bit unsure about how OAuth would be implemented for my use case as it was just for internal usage. I discovered that because I had a high trust of the client a great flow to use would be the Resource owner credentials grant.

The only real issue I face now is securing the client id and client secret. It being stored on client side is definitely an issue but form my understanding that's just one of the issues of OAuth. Fortunately if it's ever compromised I can revoke and reissue.

Anyone else that comes across this with a similar question should have a look at the following links:

http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

They really helped me understand OAuth 2.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this is a model I've seen in plenty of APIs, especially in the stateless SOA world. The "string" you're talking about is most commonly referred to as an "auth token." And all non-public API methods require the token (and for it to be valid -- expiration is essential, else someone could grab an old token) to be included with every request (with or without username -- the token should be uniquely identifiable so as to make that unnecessary, but it doesn't hurt), which means before you do anything you have to call the Login API (which does not require a token, natch) to get one before you do anything.

You may want to have your token's expiration refresh on every use (idle timeout), or else you will need to have your clients know they may need to refresh the token (i.e get a new one) every once in a while (which is somewhat more secure than an idle timeout one).

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is some kind of basic session implementation. Since REST have a stateless constraints which denies such things, I don't think that this is an acceptable solution. Afaik you have to send the username and password with every request from the trustable clients. If you have 3rd party clients, then you have to generate api keys and access tokens for them (OAuth can solve that part). If you want to know more about REST constraints, then read the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).